# Get Numbers between range having 'x' digit(s) at 'n' position

Tags: c#, .net

How can we get all the number between the range of numbers which all have the 'x' digit at their 'nth' digit position.

Example: I need to find all the tickets having number between range 1000 to 100000 which have digit 5 at 3rd digit position and 8 at 5th digit position.

I believe there should be a better option than looping over all the tickets to match the correct tickets or is it the only way which I have been doing?

Comment: Are the inputs `string` or are they `int`? perhaps you could post your current code as well

Comment: no, the inputs are list of integers, making some changes in the code, will upload code as well shortly

Comment: One alternative approach would be to *generate* the numbers, rather than finding them in a list - after all, you know what the numbers at a given set of positions are, so it's just a matter of looping through all the other posiitons, incrementing them. No idea if that would be quicker or not - you'd have to benchmark it. It would get faster the more positions you had fixed though, which could be an advantage

Comment: Of course you have to convert all the possible numbrs to string thus looping in any way. Don´t see any different appraoch.

Comment: Are you concerned about the code readability, or the performance, or something else? I.e. What are you actually trying to fix about your current implementation?

Comment: You're right, this is obvious that numbers should be converted to strings and then parsed, and yes the range is defined and numbers can be in a set.

Comment: I am trying to fix the performance of the code, cos looping over a huge set of numbers is an overhead, I am cleaning some other guys mess :p

Comment: One other optimization that springs to mind is you can remove all the numbers with fewer than 5 digits, as they can never have a digit `8` in the 5th position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also a loop but hidden:

```
var allNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1000, 100000 - 1000 + 1) // +1 to include 100000
    .Select(i => new { Number = i, String = i.ToString() })
    .Where(x => x.String.Length >= 5 && x.String[2] == '5' && x.String[4] == '8')
    .Select(x => x.Number)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This answer seems to be just what I need, I am going to test it, I think it should work.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to find out all the tickets that are in form

> 0a5bc8

where `a`, `b`, `c` are digits `[0..9]`. You can easily *generate* all the items with

```
  List<int> tickets = new List<int>(1000); // we know that there're 1000 such values

  for (int a = 0; a < 10; ++a) 
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) 
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c) 
        tickets.Add(a * 10000 + b * 100 + c * 10 + 5008);
```

No loops and *filtering out* - only generations (if you're looking for an *efficient implementation*)

Comment: But this is looping through all the numbers, which he has explicitly asked not to do in the question.

Comment: @RB. You're right, so I've completely rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a string is nothing but a list of characters you may query those elements that have the desired characters at the given indices:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(lowerBound, upperBound - lowerBound + 1)
    .Select(x => x.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'))

var result = range.Where(x => x[2] == '5' && x[4] ='8');
```

EDIT: Be aware that this appraoch changes the semantics of what the third or fifth digit within your number is, as `PadLeft` will add zero-characters in front.

Comment: But this is looping through all the numbers, which he has explicitly asked not to do in the question.

Comment: this answer also looks like would work, let me try, thanks

Comment: @ManikArora actually, you should change upperBound to upperBound - lowerBound + 1

Answer (score 0):

You could inject those known numbers in the correct positions:

> change "nnnnn" into "nn5n8nn"

You will then need to loop through 1/100th of the numbers. Convert to string, split in three parts (substring) and combine again with these numbers added.

```
Enumerable.Range(100,900)
  .Select(i => i.ToString())
  .Select(s => new { 
         p1 = s.Substring(0, 2), 
         p2 = s.Substring(2, 1), 
         p3 = s.Substring(3)})
  .Select(p => Int32.Parse(p.p1 + "5" + p.p2 + "8" + p.p3))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this looks like very interesting approach to this problem